# How to perform DNS query on iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

i want to perform some DNS queries e.g. to get IP records against a specific domain name, i am looking for a preferred way or some useful snippet for this on iOS 3.2+ SDK.
thanx in advance

part from other snippets i found this code

```
 Boolean result;
 CFHostRef hostRef;
 NSArray *addresses;
 NSString *hostname = @"apple.com";
 hostRef = CFHostCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)hostname);
 if (hostRef) {
      result = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostAddresses, NULL); // pass an error instead of NULL here to find out why it failed
      if (result == TRUE) {
           addresses = (NSArray*)CFHostGetAddressing(hostRef, &result);
      }
 }
 if (result == TRUE) {
      [addresses enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
             NSString *strDNS = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)obj))];
           NSLog(@"Resolved %d->%@", idx, strDNS);
      }];

 } else {
      NSLog(@"Not resolved");
 }
```

but this is producing same IP for every host Resolved 0->220.120.64.1 any help??

Comment: When `hostRef` is `0`, an uninitialised `result` is used in the second `if`-statement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Figured out a change in this snippet makes it working

```
if (result == TRUE) {
        NSMutableArray *tempDNS = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(addresses); i++){
            struct sockaddr_in* remoteAddr;
            CFDataRef saData = (CFDataRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(addresses, i);
            remoteAddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)CFDataGetBytePtr(saData);

            if(remoteAddr != NULL){
                // Extract the ip address
                //const char *strIP41 = inet_ntoa(remoteAddr->sin_addr);
                NSString *strDNS =[NSString stringWithCString:inet_ntoa(remoteAddr->sin_addr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"RESOLVED %d:<%@>", i, strDNS);
                [tempDNS addObject:strDNS];
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Just to add : the initial part of the code should be  
    Boolean result;
    CFHostRef hostRef;
    CFArrayRef addresses = NULL;
    hostname = @"apple.com";
    hostRef = CFHostCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)hostname);
    if (hostRef) {
        result = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostAddresses, NULL); 
        if (result == TRUE) {
            addresses = CFHostGetAddressing(hostRef, &result);
        }
    }

Answer (score 7):

Bros there is a lot simpler way! Thanks to iOS being a unix system, you become a god with unlimited power and resource! I present elegance.

```
- (NSString*)lookupHostIPAddressForURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    // Ask the unix subsytem to query the DNS
    struct hostent *remoteHostEnt = gethostbyname([[url host] UTF8String]);
    // Get address info from host entry
    struct in_addr *remoteInAddr = (struct in_addr *) remoteHostEnt->h_addr_list[0];
    // Convert numeric addr to ASCII string
    char *sRemoteInAddr = inet_ntoa(*remoteInAddr);
    // hostIP
    NSString* hostIP = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sRemoteInAddr];
    return hostIP;
}
```

Comment: the requirement is not a host-to-IP query but it is a DNS query and a host usually have more than one DNS entries including, NS, A, MX

Comment: Be careful. gethostbyname is not re-entrant. There will be problem when you try to dns lookup different domains in multi-thread. I have encountered the problem.