# How to get All DNS records with iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i am looking for so long to get a solution regarding getting DNS records by using iOS SDK???

i am able to resolve ip addesses against host name [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000441/how-to-perform-dns-query-on-ios) but that is not what i want... i need to get all DNS records including **PTR**, **Name**, **NS**, **MX**, **CNAME** etc.. please your help or a code snippet is very much appreciated

Comment: What did you end up doing, if I may inquire?

Answer (score 2):

Try exploring

```
DNSServiceErrorType DNSSD_API DNSServiceQueryRecord
    (
    DNSServiceRef                       *sdRef,
    DNSServiceFlags                     flags,
    uint32_t                            interfaceIndex,
    const char                          *fullname,
    uint16_t                            rrtype,
    uint16_t                            rrclass,
    DNSServiceQueryRecordReply          callBack,
    void                                *context  /* may be NULL */
    );
```

from

```
#include <dns_util.h>
```

I have actually written my objective-c wrapper using this function for all kinds of DNS records..but i cant get time to publish it somewhere

Answer (score 1):

In case others come across this in their search and want to see more details:

I found it to be from `#include <dns_sd.h>`

```
// domain is a NSString
DNSServiceRef sdRef;
DNSServiceQueryRecord(&sdRef, 0, 0, [domain UTF8String], kDNSServiceType_MX, kDNSServiceClass_IN, callBack, NULL);
DNSServiceProcessResult(sdRef);
DNSServiceRefDeallocate(sdRef);
```

This is for if you wanted the MX records for a domain. `callBack` is a C method

```
static void callBack(
                         DNSServiceRef       sdRef,
                         DNSServiceFlags     theFlags,
                         uint32_t            theInterfaceIndex,
                         DNSServiceErrorType theErrorCode,
                         const char*         theName,
                         uint16_t            theType,
                         uint16_t            theClass,
                         uint16_t            theDataLength,
                         const void*         theData,
                         uint32_t            theTTL,
                         void*               theContext)
{
    // do your magic here...
}
```

The callback method is called once it finds a response, note that you can receive multiple callbacks.  For example when checking the domain of my office email I received 7 call backs.

Comment: After having some issues I found that you really should be using DNSServiceQueryRecord and DNSServiceSetDispatchQueue. Don't forget to add a timeout flag (second param).